# How can i change an arraylist object (int , string, boolean "false") to (int,String,boolean"true") and return it back to the array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, call

I'm fairly new to programing and I'm working on a library interface to get better acquainted with some of the aspects of java. What I'm trying to do is call a `checkOutBook();` method where the user enters the book isbn, an if statement iterates threw the arraylist looking for that isbn.
    If it's there I get the index to try to call the book object to change the boolean value to false to show that the book is not available. But i can't figure out how to do it. It's been a few days of looking.

```
public void checkout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int q =  l.getReturnB();
    if (Cat.cat.contains(q)){

        book r = Cat.cat.get(q);
        book b = new book(b.getIsbn(),b.getTitle(),b.c); // c = the         boolean value which is true. 
        r(b.getIsbn(),b.getTitle(),false);
        Cat.cat.add(r);
    }
```

Comment: using meaningful names for your objects, methods and parameters is one of the most important thing you need to learn while you are starting programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method inside your book class called checkOut which changes the book's boolean value to false. Call that method inside your if statement.

```
if(Cat.cat.contains(q))
{

book r = Cat.cat.get(q);
r.checkOut();

}
```